# VLOOKUP issue with Excel 2013 (getting #N/A)

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have successfully troubleshot VLOOKUP issues for years but this one has me stumped. I'm referencing between lists by full names (John Doe, for example) but getting #N/A. I've already tried TRIM (didn't change anything and by inspection I can see that there are no extra spaces in the original data anyway). I also tried Text-to-Columns, which in the past has magically fixed my VLOOKUPs but not now. I also tried a Stack Overflow suggestion to check each pair of names using the CODE function but both have the same numerical Code.

I've attached a sample file containing the issue.

[Vlookup Excel File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqE-xpguAOIliTob4XcIl7_8BGqx)

Comment: What's the formula? What does your data look like? I (and I assume most others) are unlikely to download files/workbooks, especially when macros may be involved.  Could you kindly post a sample data table, and what the formula you're using is?

Comment: The space characters' codes do not match (one of them is 32 and the other one is 194).

Comment: Thanks Ayhan. How did you determine that the space characters' codes do not match? When I apply the CODE function to both I get 80. Also, do you know how to fix the issue to get the VLOOKUP working? Thanks!

Comment: @Malcolm Scott seems to have illustrated it very well below. I also checked using MID formula (although he gets a different code, I don't know why).

Comment: @Malcolm The code function only looks at one character, the first in the string that is why you get 80 for both.

Comment: Thanks Ayhan. I hadn't noticed Scott's answer but now I have reviewed it and it is indeed useful. Regards, Malcolm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that space in between Paul and Casey is not a normal space in B3.

To illustrate I put This in F1:

```
=CODE(MID($A$1,ROW(1:1),1))
```

And in G1:

```
=CODE(MID($B$3,ROW(1:1),1))
```

And copied down.

[image]

`32` is what we want but the space in B3 is `160`

To fix this we can substitute the 160 for 32:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(B3,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)),A1,1,0)
```

[image]